# Valid way of using sprite-sheet images for HTML5

Tags: css, html, sprite-sheet

I have some global images I will use  throughout the website. What is the proper markup for HTML5 to use these kind of elements. Can I use img tag without src attribute or should I just use divs instead and not worry about the alt tags or the way you could see on the code is fine?

```css
.social-links div{
display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.icon-icon-facebook {
  background-image: url(../images/global/spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -111px -145px;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
}
.icon-icon-google-plus {
  background-image: url(../images/global/spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -134px -145px;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
}
.icon-icon-instagram {
  background-image: url(../images/global/spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -124px -111px;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
}
.icon-icon-linkedin {
  background-image: url(../images/global/spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -147px -111px;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
}
.icon-icon-pinterest {
  background-image: url(../images/global/spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -170px -111px;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
}
.icon-icon-twitter {
  background-image: url(../images/global/spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -65px -145px;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
}
.icon-icon-youtube {
  background-image: url(../images/global/spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -88px -145px;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
}
```

```html
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <ul class="social-links">
              <li><div role="img" class="icon-icon-facebook" title="facebook icon"></div>Facebook</li>
              <li><div role="img" class="icon-icon-twitter" title="twitter icon"></div>Twitter</li>
              <li><div role="img" class="icon-icon-pinterest" title="pinterest icon"></div>Pinterest</li>
              <li><div role="img" class="icon-icon-instagram" title="instagram icon"></div>Instagram</li>
              <li><div role="img" class="icon-icon-google-plus" title="google-plus icon"></div>Google Plus</li>
              <li><div role="img" class="icon-icon-linkedin" title="linkedin icon"></div>LinkedIn</li>
              <li><div role="img" class="icon-icon-youtube" title="youtube icon"></div>YouTube</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: you may use a pseudo element (::before/:before) and set class on li (or <a>link</a>) since it is design purpose, no need of role attribute or, alternative text wich is already standing here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use it on `:before` elements. Since the icon is followed by a text, you don't need the role attribute in here. Also, the icon is here to support the text in a "design" matter, it doesn't add anything to your document so you don't have to add a title to it.

Plus, the "img" role is not valid in HTML5. Take a look at the documentation here for more informations about role:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/PF/XTech/HTML5/RoleAttribute

I'd do it like this:

HTML

```
     <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="social-links">
          <li class="facebook">Facebook</li>
          <...></...>
         </ul>
     </div>
```

CSS

```
 .social-link .facebook:before {
    background-image: url(../images/global/spritesheet.png);
    background-position: -111px -145px;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px /* Set the desired margin here */;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
 }
```

For more information about the :before pseudo element, take a look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/%3Abefore

Comment: How about the other UI elements without text like website logo or arrows? I'll be adding those to the sprite later on.

Comment: @TanKucukhas if your image has a meaning, then it should stand in the html (img tag), if it is only design purpose, it can stand as a background or pseudo-element. test your page without any style to find out if it should be there  or not.

Comment: If, for instance, you use an arrow, i'd use a button HTML5 element, with a title on it and the effect that it does. It always depends, if it's an external link, then you can use a link with a title attribute on it and use the icon on a span with a class on it (a little bit like you did in your example)

Comment: I also agree with @GCyrillus, if the image has a meanning then it deserve to be in the img tag since it's part of your content. Background image won't be read on a div as if it was a part of your content by screen-readers or crawler.